# Removing padding and margins in Wordpress for Mobile via CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having some issues with my website in Wordpress in Mobile view.

Unforntalty my CSS skills are somewhat limited, but I have managed to remove what I think is most of it via the code below, you can view one of the problematic pages - https://acmegraphics.co.uk/portfolio-item/food-supermarkets/

Am I ignoring anything or does anyone see any issues with the code I'm using?

```
.single-portfolio-item .mkdf-content .mkdf-content-inner > .mkdf-container > .mkdf-container-inner {
padding-top: 20px !important;


.single-portfolio-item .mkdf-portfolio-single-holder.mkdf-ps-slider-layout .mkdf-ps-image-holder {
margin: 0 0 20px;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In the code you posted the closing curly brackets  `}`  for both CSS rules are missing. If that isn't a typo (?), it is probably the cause for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not ideal to use `!important` but since it works it' ok. My only concern is that you mentioned that you have the problem in mobile view and your rule is for all devices, you better wrap it in a media query like like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.single-portfolio-item .mkdf-content .mkdf-content-inner > .mkdf-container > .mkdf-container-inner {
padding-top: 20px !important;}


.single-portfolio-item .mkdf-portfolio-single-holder.mkdf-ps-slider-layout .mkdf-ps-image-holder {
margin: 0 0 20px;}
}
```